# gnome-terminal starts recursively when execute bash script

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

I have bash script and i want to execute it in Ubuntu by double-clicking on that script

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c '$(pwd)/copyResources.sh; exec bash'
```

This call gnome-terminal when i execute copyResources.sh. But it keep open recursively new windows. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made link to the script and it works pretty well

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c '/home/scripts/copyResources.sh; exec bash'
```